# Count of number of columns using rowdatabound

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to find count of total number of columns in a gridview inside the event rowdatabound .Is there any way for it.
Below is my few code:

```
   protected void gvEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lnkView = new LinkButton();
            lnkView.ID = "lnkView";
            lnkView.Text = "View";
            lnkView.Click += ViewDetails; 
            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lnkView);
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear why you wouldn't just use `gvEmployee.Columns.Count`, could you provide more detail on why you need this inside the event handler for a row being data bound?

Comment: @Sven Grosen : I had created gridview dynamically and i wanted to replace e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lnkView); ,cells[3] to more specific code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast sender to `GridView` and get the count.

```
protected void gvEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{      
    if(!(sender is GridView))
        return;

    GridView gridView = (GridView) sender;
    var colCount = gridView.Columns.Count;

   //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want this, but `Cells` is an array of the cells in this row, so to get the total number of columns:

```
protected void gvEmployee_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {            
        var colCount = e.Row.Cells.Count;
    }
```

Comment: i had created gridview dynamically and i wanted to replace  e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lnkView); ,cells[3] to more specific code.

Comment: i am getting an error for .Length. Can you please tel me why is it ?

Comment: It should be `Count`, not `Length`